# Mercurial: Change username of some commits not pushed yet?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I made a few commits, but I realised later on that I haven't had my username setup properly. I changed it and made a few more commits with the right username. Is there any way to change the first commits to use the new username before pushing all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would accomplish your goal, it relies on [`mq` extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension), Mercurial's patch queue. (Updated to include [@MarkTolonen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/235698/mark-tolonen) fantastic comment!)

Step 0. Back up your work! (you can create a local throw-away clone to try this out)

1. Enable the `mq` extension in your config files (see help [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension))
2. use `hg qimport` to import into the patch queue the changesets you want to edit
3. use `hg qpop -a` to pull those patches off the applied patch stack
4. push the first patch on with `hg qpush`
5. use `hg qref -U` to update the patch's author to the current user (or use `hg qref -u <username>` to set it explicityly)
6. repeat steps 4. and 5. for each patch in the queue.
7. double check your work - Is your username appearing correct in the log now?
8. use `hg qfin -a` to finalize the patches into changesets
9. you should now be ready to push the updated changesets to the public repo

---

My original steps included manually setting the user in a text editor, which were in place of steps 4-6 above:

A. open the folder `.hg\patches`, you should have a `###.diff` file for each changeset
B. open those in the text editor of your choice
C. edit the line at the top that starts with `# User <your old user name>`
   and update it to be `# User <your new user name>`
D. save the patches
E. use `hg push -a` to push them back onto the applied stack

Comment: After `hg qpop -a` you can also `hg qpush` one patch at a time and `hg qref -U` on to update to the current user information instead of editing each patch manually.  Also `hg qref -u <username>` to specify it explicitly.

Comment: That would be much easier! I've edited that into the list of steps. Thank you @MarkTolonen!

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest (and fastest) way is [convert your repository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--authors_.2F_--authormap) from Mercurial to Mercurial with special `--authormap` for replacing old username with new